# whats the syntax for a UDF that inserts into a table with only a PK identity field?

Tags: sql-server-2005, user-defined-functions

i am getting errors in trying to make a UDF to wrap the logic of generating primary keys for use in some procs doing inserts into DB tables.

i have the following pk table for generating values for use in stored procs:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PK](
 [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT [PK_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 (
 [Id] ASC
 )
)
```

my UDF is this:

```
alter FUNCTION [getPK] ( )  
RETURNS int
AS  
BEGIN  
declare @Output int 
    INSERT INTO pk default values
    SET @Output = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY())
    RETURN @Output
END
```

Im trying to encapsulate the following logic for use i multiple places in my DB:

```
INSERT INTO pk default values
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() --to get a new ID
```

Comment: ... why are you doing this at all? What is the point of the PK table? The actual tables you're inserting into should be maintaining their own primary keys.

Comment: Side note: In your table, `Id` is a bigint, but your function returns an int.

Comment: You are trying to implement a sequence. Why? Didn't you read the answers to your previous question where **no-one** agreed wth "your colleague"? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237807/whats-better-identity-columns-or-generated-unique-id-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A UDF **can not** change database state. That is, it can't write to tables.

Did you read the answers to your previous question? Did anyone suggest this was a good idea? Bother here or SO and on DBA.SE?

Comment: point taken, I want to create a POC since its kind of along the same lined of development anyhow.